# different layouts for different errors in cakephp1.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Is it possible to set different layouts for different errors in cakephp1.3?

this is my **AppError** class

```
function _outputMessage($template) {
    $this->controller->beforeFilter();
    $this->controller->render($template);
    $this->controller->afterFilter();
    echo $this->controller->output;
}

function error404($params) {
    extract($params, EXTR_OVERWRITE);
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    $this->error(array('code' => '404',
                    'name' => 'Not found',
                    'message' => sprintf("page not found %s", $url, $message),
                    'base' => $base));

    exit();
}

function item404($params) {
    extract($params, EXTR_OVERWRITE);
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");

    $this->error(array('code' => '404',
                    'name' => 'Not found',
                    'message' => sprintf("Item not found %s", $url, $message),
                    'base' => $base));

    exit();
}
```

I want to have layout "error" and layout "itemerror", respectively.
I have tried setting the layout in the functions, but it does not work.

Any help appreciated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just change the layout of the controller.

```
$this->controller->layout = 'error_layout';
```

This assumes you continue using the default `_outputMessage()` method.

```
function _outputMessage($template) {
    // can be set in the error method
    $this->controller->layout = 'error_layout';
    parent::_outputMessage($template);
}
```

Comment: i want to have LayoutA for ErrorA and LayoutB for ErrorB. Setting the controller layout does not allow for this differentiation

Comment: It should if you set it in the error rather than `_outputMessage`, as noted in the comment. After all, it uses `$this->controller` to do the rendering. Did you remove your `_outputMessage` so it uses the default? You don't need to overwrite it.

Comment: setting $this->controller->layout = 'error_layout'; in the error methods causes for the default layout to be used.

Comment: As long as you do it before `_outputMessage` and you don't have anything else setting the layout, it should work. I'll ask again: are you still using your `_outputMessage`? Maybe post your whole app error class so I can take a look.

Comment: FOUND THE PROBLEM! you were right, but i had this code $this->error(array('code' => '404',
      'name' => 'Not found',
      'message' => sprintf("Not found", $url),
      'base' => $base));  in both methods, which messed everything up.